# React: [Label]-[input]-[edit btn]-[save btn-(hidden)]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, use-effect, use-state

As the title states, Ive got a simple crud operation I could use some help with the useEffect/useState hook in how to implement.

[image: form input/userdetails]

I've got the input set to disabled by default, displaying the previous value via the placeholder. The state is then updated via a useState/useEffect hooks. Also, the second button (save) is set to hidden by default.

**Goal:**

- essentially, just trying to setup an event listener for each edit-input button: hide the edit button, enable the input, unhide the save button.
- with a separate (2nd) event listener on the save button: to hide the save button, unhide the edit button, return the input to disabled, turn the placeholder to the new value, and submit the value(I've got a good idea of the last part)

**JSX:**

```
<label className="col">
  <div className="row">
    <p className="bold nowrap inline-value-title" >Test Name:&nbsp; </p>
    <input 
      id="display-name-change"
      type="text"
      className="form-reset inline-input"
      onChange={(e) => setDisplayName(e.target.value)}
      value={displayName}
      placeholder={user.displayName}
      disabled
    />
    <button type="button" className="inline-button edit-val-btn">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare}  />
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="hidden inline-button save-val-btn">.  
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleCheck}  />
    </button>
  </div>
</label>
```

**My Javascript:** (as you can probably tell it's still very Vanilla and I think that's the problem)...

```
const editValueBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-val-btn');
const saveValueBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.save-val-btn');

useEffect(() => {
    editValueBtns.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            button.classList.add('hidden')
            button.nextSibling.classList.remove('hidden')
            button.parentElement.children[1].removeAttr("disabled") ;
        })
    })

    saveValueBtns.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            button.classList.add('hidden')
            button.previousSibling.classList.remove('hidden')
            button.parentElement.children[1].addAttr("disabled") ;
        })
    })
}, []);
```

**EDIT: Showing the inputs being submitted to Firebase/Firestore**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let selectedFile = document.querySelector('#thumbnailInput')

    // displayname
    if(displayName.length == 0){console.log('No change of name')} 
    else { 
        console.log('change to displayname')
        updateProfile(user, { displayName })
        setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), { displayName }, { merge: true })

    }

    // phone Number
    if (phoneNo.length == 0){console.log('No change of phone no')}
    else {
        console.log('change to phone')
        updateProfile(user, { phoneNo })
        setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), { phoneNo }, { merge: true })
    }

    // title
    if (title.length == 0){console.log('No change of title')}
    else {
        console.log('change to title')
        updateProfile(user, { title })
        setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), { title }, { merge: true })
    }

    // avatar thumbnail
    if(selectedFile.files[0] == undefined){
        console.log('no change to thumbnail')
    } else {
        console.log('change to thumbnail')
        // pass the path in ref to create a StorageReference
        const storageRef = ref(storage,`thumbnails/${user.uid}/${displayName}`) //thumbnail.name

        // upload image, file is a blob here
        await uploadBytes(storageRef, thumbnail);

        const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

        // this function returns promise too, add await 
        await updateProfile(user, { photoURL: downloadUrl })

        updateProfile(user, { photoURL: downloadUrl})

        setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
            photoURL: downloadUrl,
        }, { merge: true })
    }

    // clear all form inputs
    const inputs = e.target.querySelectorAll('.form-reset')
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
        input.value=""
    })
}
```

Comment: EDIT: for some reason the console.log()'s are preventing the rest of the code so I commented them out... The buttons are toggling now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your vanilla js way, and raise you the react way. In react, you shouldn't have to use document.querySelector, previousSibling, parentElement, classList.add, classList.remove, addAttr or button.addEventListener. See solution in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/muddy-river-r7gofi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) or below:

**App.jsx**

```
import { Row } from "./components/Row";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row placeholder="input 1" />
      <Row placeholder="input 2" />
      <Row placeholder="input 3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Row.jsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const Row = ({ defaultValue, placeholder }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setDisabled(false);
  };

  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    setDisabled(true);
    // save logic goes here
  };

  return (
    <label className="col">
      <div className="row">
        <p className="bold nowrap inline-value-title">Test Name:</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-reset inline-input"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
          }}
          value={value}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
        {disabled && (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={handleEditClick}
            className="inline-button edit-val-btn"
          >
            edit
          </button>
        )}
        {!disabled && (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={handleSaveClick}
            className="hidden inline-button save-val-btn"
          >
            save
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </label>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thats beautiful! Looks and works great! and soo much less code. Thank you! It's stuff like this that really makes React so much more comfortable.

Comment: So, I'm stuck implementing this. I updated my original question with how I previously took the inputs and completed sending the data from each input to firebase properly. Now, with this solution, each input has identical properties (with the exception of the placeholder) but for instance if I wanted to access the value of a particular input, How to I distinguish 1 element as a display name, or a title, to perform unique functions depending upon the input?

Answer (score 0):

**small tweaks**.. it appears that logging the console kept it from doing what it did. also removed the e from the parenthesis after each 'click'. the addAttr and removeAttr also were replaced... the rest of the functionality can be placed in either of the listeners..

**EDIT:** added a 2nd input and it appears to only work in the 1st input....
...yes I'm talking to myself.

**EDIT 2:** It worked fine until the page refreshed... removed the dependency array for it to work every time. I feel like i still need a cleanup function, but I can't just place the event listeners into a function can i? Really, if you're reading this i would love some more experienced input... :)

```
useEffect(() => {
    editValueBtns.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            button.classList.add('hidden')
            button.nextSibling.classList.remove('hidden')
            button.parentElement.children[1].disabled = false ;
        })
    })

    saveValueBtns.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            button.classList.add('hidden')
            button.previousSibling.classList.remove('hidden')
            button.parentElement.children[1].disabled = true ;
        })
    })
});
```